# is it correct: a pencil with length of 5cm?

Tags: word-usage

For example,

```
a pencil with length of 5cm
a harddisk with size of 100GB
```

something like that, is it correct?

Comment: "*a* length", "*a* size"

Comment: *A 5-cm-long pencil; a 100-GB harddisk!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statements would sound more natural if you added an indefinite article before the second noun. Also, "harddisk" should be two separate words. Finally, most English speakers agree that numbers below ten should be written with letters rather than numerals in formal contexts.

`a pencil with a length of 5cm
a hard disk with a size of 100GB`

In some cases, the attribute being referred to is implied by the unit of measurement. One would typically refer to `a 100GB hard disk`
and it would be understood that 100GB described its size (i.e. storage capacity). In cases of describing physical dimensions, it is common to use a compound adjective like `a five-centimeter-long pencil`, `a two-meter-wide doorway`, or `six-foot-tall dog`.